# Restore deleted Instagram account created using Facebook login

Tags: instagram, account-recovery

I had created my Instagram account using my Facebook account. Recently I deleted my Instagram account and now I'm wondering if there is a way I could get it back. Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, if your account was deleted by you or someone with your password, there's no way to restore it. You can create a new account with the same email address you used before, but you may not be able to get the same username.

But here is a [third party tool](http://useful-info.org/t/ig_account_recovery/) which says you can recover your deleted account with the help of this tool. You can give a try if you want.

<sup>*Note:* I have never used this tool.</sup>